# How to resolve greendao build errors

Tags: android, build.gradle, greendao

I am working on an android application which uses GreenDao (ORM) for Object Relation mapping . I have defined entity classes in my code. When i build the code , greendao generates Dao classes corresponding to the entities.

It also generates DaoMaster and DaoSession classes. So using DaoSession and Dao classes i start coding and implemented by logic. Now when i commit to github , i do not want to push the generated files. Since my code is dependant on generated files, when someone takes my code from github , he does not get the generated file (because i did not push them). So he gets build errors that some classes are not there like DaoMaster and DaoSession etc.

To overcome this , he has to comment all the code which uses these generated files and build it. Now build succeeds and DaoMaster and DaoSession gets generated. Now he has to uncomment the previously commented code . Because now the classes are generated.

But this approach seems very tedious because there can be a lot of code.
So i was thinking may be if there is a way to generate the Dao files first before the source code is built. I mean when i start the build command , is there a way to specify that first build this , then this . So that  first the greenDao library gets built and DaoMaster , DaoSession and Daos are generated and then source code gets built and since now Dao files are available it will succeed.

Or may be there is some other way to do this. I tried to find options for first approach , but could not find much help .Please suggest how to tackle this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one solution for this. When some one takes the git pull , he will not have any greendao generated files. To generate those those files just run :

./gradlew greendao .
This will generate all the necessary Dao files . So after that we can build the code without any errors.

Comment: where and how to run this command? can you give a reference for where did you find your solution?